# In AngularJS routing, how templateUrl works without pointing to a .html file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to understand the AngularJS routing when it is used with ASP.net MVC. I am following this [article](https://josephjefferson.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/merging-asp-net-mvc-and-angularjs-routing/) to understand AngularJS routing. My query is specific to the usage of 'templateURL'. I understand that in pure AngularJS routing, templateUrl points to a specific '.html' page. But in the many example applications that I have seen in the internet for AngularJS and ASP.net MVC, I have seen that templateURL does not point to a specific .html, but a path of the view folder is given, not the .html file (or .cshtml file, which i know can be processed only by ASP.net MVC framework). For example from the article, following is the routing information given in the AngularJS javascript:

```
    NbCapp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/ondemand', {
 controller: 'onDemandController',
 templateUrl: 'ondemand/ondemand'
 })
 .when('/results', {
 controller: 'resultsController',
 templateUrl: 'results/results'
 })
 .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/results' });
});
```

As observed from the above, all the routing, points to a folder not a .html file. Could anyone please help me understand how this works.

Comment: I suggest reading up a bit on ASP.NET MVC. I could explain its routing model here, but I think you'd benefit much more from actually going through some of the excellent material available online. In short, to request a .cshtml file you always request what looks like a "folder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that in pure AngularJS routing, templateUrl points to a specific '.html' page.

Not necessarily. It doesn't matter what extension is or whether there is extension at all or not. The only thing that matters is [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) of the document fetched as template. So as long as it's `text/html` - it can be used as template. (Actually GET request for template will be issued and response processed as template (will be displayed on the page), so it doesn't even matter what server responds with Angular will just take `responseText` of the response data, but better if it is `text/html`).

In your example, `templateUrl: 'results/results'` might point to some dynamic framework resolved user-friendly path without any extensions, which responds with HTML content.

Comment: In the case of ASP.net MVC, 'results/results' is actually a View (.cshtml), which AngularJS has no knowledge about. So, then why do we need to mention 'results/results' at all in templateUrl?. What will happen if I don't mention it in the templateUrl?

Comment: I don't know how ASP.net resolves (routes and maps) requests, but if it points to a view file then it means that if you load in browser `http://your.server/some/path/to/your/project/results/results` (check in network tab of the console for exact URL) you will see HTML content of this file. This is all Angular needs - text content from the response. It doesn't need extension.

Comment: I have accepted your post as answer. Husein Roncevic has also provided good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`AngularJS` does not necessarily have to point to an HTML page. What you have specified above is a combination of controller/action. When you call an action you get a processed CSHTML, VBHTML, or ASPX as an HTML response.

For example, specifying:

```
templateUrl: 'Account/LogOn'
```

will instantiate an **AccountController** and call **LogOn** action that will return `PartialViewResult`.

Comment: Do you mean to say that AngularJS FW knows that "Account" is a controller and "Logon" is an Action?. In my example code, I have also mentioned a Controller, which is also calling a service which calls a MVC controller which returns a View. In this case, then what is the use of specific mention of controller through 'controller' if templateUrl also points to a controller?

Comment: AngularJS does not need to know that you are running MVC, WebForms, NodeJS, or whatever technology you decide to use. AngularJS is a client-side framework. When it calls Account/LogOn, it does not care how the server will resolve this. All it cares is that it gets an HTML response in return. In case of your MVC application, the application running on your server is an MVC application and as such a request for Account/LogOn will be served by the MVC controller and action. The server will know how to process this and AngularJS will know what to do with the response that it receives.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl does not require only .html template. Basically ui-route loads the content from given template url and accept that  Content-Type : 'text/html'. Template loadin g is done by ajax.

So you are free to load any template with any extension but with valid path.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net MVC we define custom routing in RouteConfig File. Suppose in RouteConfig we have declared custom route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("AngularTemplates", "almight/{name}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Template" });
```

and in app.js file, we have configured angular route as follow:-

```
var app = angular.module("BeautyParlorAppModule", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
debugger

$routeProvider
      .when("/DetailView",
              {
                  templateUrl: "almight/detailsView",
                  controller: "DetailviewController"
              }
      )
      .when("/ListView",
              {
                  templateUrl: "almight/_ListView",
                  controller: "ListViewController"
              }
      );
});
```

In HTML file we have action like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/#/ListView">Show ListView</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/DetailView">Show DetailView</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking on link will locate home controller of MVC and call action `Template` with `Name` parameters `_ListView` or `detailsView`

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string id)

        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Template(string name)
        {
            if (name == null || !Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[-\w]+$"))
                throw new ArgumentException("Illegal template name", name");

                                    relativeViewPath=String.Format("~/Views/Home/{0}.cshtml",name);    
            return View(relativeViewPath);
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```